# I'm seeing website that is not mine in access.log

Tags: linux, monitoring, logging

I'm just wondering why there are some website on my access.log that is not mine.

Can anyone tell me if my site is used as a proxy?

Here's the log:

```
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:56 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/import-lowhorn-gets-high-marks-from-teammates-after-week-with-ginebra" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:57 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.starmometer.com/2013/07/21/ina-kapatid-anak-shoes-now-available-in-cln-stores/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:57 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/import-lowhorn-gets-high-marks-from-teammates-after-week-with-ginebra" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:57 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:58 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0.8112.16421; Windows NT 6.1)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:58 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/import-lowhorn-gets-high-marks-from-teammates-after-week-with-ginebra" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:58 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/import-lowhorn-gets-high-marks-from-teammates-after-week-with-ginebra" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:23:59 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/import-lowhorn-gets-high-marks-from-teammates-after-week-with-ginebra" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:11 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:11 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.inquirer.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:11 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:12 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:14 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:15 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:15 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:18 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:18 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:19 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://edge.sharethis.com/share5x/index.e115b54ab48f7ff40187e46edec2497a.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:20 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:24 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:24:24 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 7722 "http://www.spin.ph/sports/basketball/news/scuffle-after-feu-ust-game" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:26:10 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/lightbox2/images/next.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 305 "http://www.mysite.com.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:26:10 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/lightbox2/images/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "http://www.mysite.com.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
121.54.66.50 - - [22/Jul/2013:08:26:10 +0800] "GET /sites/all/modules/lightbox2/images/prev.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 307 "http://www.mysite.com.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
```

The last 3 line is legitimate log. Just wondering why there are site like spin.ph, starmometer.com, sharethis.com, inquirer.net.

Do I need to worry of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 8th field is the referrer field.  It shows which URL the visitor traveled from to get to your site.  However, in this case, it's probably just an attempt to poison any web stats you're generating (like webalizer), with links to those sites, to increase their traffic.  The page they all request from you is just your root page (the "GET /" bit).

You don't need to worry, but you shouldn't make Webalizer (or similar) reports with referrer links public, for this very reason (not sure if you are, just thought I'd mention it).

I'm going to guess you're using Apache 2, here's [more info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) on the log formats.

NB: it's always possible of course, that they're legitimate referrals, from those sites, it depends what content is on your website.